# Hostinger no me permite iniciar $_COOKIES

Tags: php, html, cookies

espero que me puedan apoyar con este problema particular, este es el pedazo o fragmento de código que está declarado actualmente, lo que hago aquí es inicializar las cookies con los valores de "id_usuario, tipo_usuario, correo", actualmente en mi computadora de manera local funciona correctamente e incluso en otros hostings.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
El resultado de esto es lo que te muestro a continuación, este código lo puse de ejemplo para que se puedan visualizar las cookies, es esta primera imagen se observa que aún no han sido creadas las cookies, solo aparecen 2 que pertenecen a la información de la conexión.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
En esta siguiente imágen, se muestran las nuevas cookies que se crearon, este es el resultado esperado.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
De hecho si lo compruebo en las opciones del propio navegador, me aparecen como se muestra a continuación.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Ahora bien, en la parte de Hostinger debería mostrar lo que les enseñe anteriormente, pero puedes observar que en la siguiente fotografía, solo aparecen los primeros 2 cookies después de hacer el proceso que inicializa las mismas, y para que se note que estoy en el dominio, la flecha rosada muestra que se está imprimiendo el nombre del dominio o ruta del proyecto actual, y dice "liaabogados.com" el texto de "app_key: D56...." Esa es la primera cookie por defecto.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Y si comprobamos en el navegador, no aparecen inicializadas.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Cabe mencionar, que tambien intente inicializar la cookie de la manera más fácil y sencilla que te sugiere el manual de php, pero tampoco la crea, incluso intente crearla con valores estáticos o definidos, que no dependan de una consulta u otro proceso anterior, pero ni así funciono, de igual manera baje la versión de PHP en las configuraciones de hosting pero tampoco funciona, agradecería mucho su apoyo.

Comment: El código y los mensajes de error siempre _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes.

Answer (score 0):

me paso igual con banahosting, le mande un mensaje al área de soporte pensando que podría tratarse de algún bloqueo por seguridad en la generación de cookies y me contestaron que no. Por lo que decidí hacer pruebas con un archivo simple para generar una cookie y tampoco funciono, comparto lo que me funciono:

1 Eliminar saltos de líneas y espacios antes de las etiquetas de php.

2 Ordenar el código evitando que antes de la creación de la cookie hubiera algún "echo", "print", etc.

3 Colocar antes de empezar el código "ob_start();".

4 especifique el dominio en la cookie setcookie("galleta", "probamos", time()3600,"/", ".mi-dominio.com");

5 Guardar el archivo en UTF-8 sin BOM.

después de esto se creo la bendita galleta sin problemas, en caso resuelva su problema y después quiera eliminarla lo mas fácil es setearle una hora de expiración en negativo.

espero pueda ayudar a alguien con esto, en agradecimiento de tantas veces que me he servido de esta pagina. saludos a todos.